# What's the font used in 'Linear Algebra' by Friedberg?

Tags: fonts, printing, typefaces

I'm writing a math-related document in LaTex and want to use the font in which the book 'Linear Algebra' by Stephen Friedberg was printed. Does anybody know what font might it be? So far I've tried Arial, Latin Modern and Gyre Pagella but none of them seems to fit quite right.

[image: This is a sample definition from the book]

Comment: It looks like a usual Computer Modern, which is the default font with LaTeX.

Comment: It is interesting to see that they use the slanted cmr in the Definition and the italic cmr after it. I wonder if that was on purpose.